# Non .NET job is listed when filtering through the '.net' tag (careers)

Tags: bug, jobs, tag-filters

By looking for jobs with the '.net' tag, i.e., this URL: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/.net?pg=3 I've come across many jobs that don't have it. They don't have the tag and they don't have the '.net' text in their content either.

A current example is this one: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/97274/devops-automation-engineer-m-f-delivery-hero

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because the ".net" text is not even in the job offer, so it's not a tag vs text query issue

Comment: It is the same problem ultimately, because it's a full-text search. In your example job listing there are words in there which start with "net", plus something called "ru-Net", so these might be terms that get included as well. Notice how searching for ".net" gives you exactly the same results as searching for "net" (without the initial dot).

Comment: precisely because of what you said, it's not a duplicate, it's a bug in the search about ignoring the "." character

Comment: as I'm a programmer myself, my guess is that the "." here is acting as a wildcard in a regular expression, so the bug is about considering the text to be searched as being a regular expression instead of normal text